# How to test result from page.evaluateHandle & el.nextElementSibling?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

How do you test that **child** actually contains the next Element Sibling or if there was NO next sibling found?

```
child = await page.evaluateHandle(el => el.nextElementSibling, child);
```

Nothing I've found seems to work. :(

Answer (score 2):

Finally figured it out.

**.nextElementSibling** - returns a Node object or null.

**.evaluateHandle** - returns a jsHandle containing that result.

So you have to process the jsHandle container which holds the result.

**jsHandle.asElement()** - Returns either null or the object handle itself, if the object handle is an instance of ElementHandle.

You test for a failed result with:

```
if (child.asElement() === null) {
//do something
}
```